# jQuery Tabs not clickable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have jQuery tab, it works perfectly, I want to make the tabs to **not be clickable** and that can be done by removing `href` from a tags but this will cause the tabs to crash, is there a way to remove links from the tabs without causing a crash?

I will add next and back buttons on each tab so user can move one tab each time. I want to make it as wizard but in the side-tabs style.

**Note:** I have an idea, to remove `href` from a tag when mouse over and put the `href` parameter and hat can be done by using toggle function, but I need your help to do that, any other ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either disable them:

```
$('#tabs').tabs({
    disabled: [0,1,2,3]
});
```

Or you could remove the click event:

```
$('#tabs')
    .tabs()
    .find('.ui-tabs-nav a')
        .unbind('click.tabs');
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/uMLhv/)**

Comment: thank you guys (Didier and Johan) for your help, I really appreciate that.

Answer (score 2):

Disable them?

```
$(".tabs").tabs({
    disabled: [2]  //disable third tab. you can pass an array of indexes here like [0,1,2,3,4]
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WqPtr/5/